What's the correct usage of a bit , a little , rather, a lot , much ..?
Can I say this?

I can't buy this mobile phone. It's a bit / a little / a lot / much expensive for me.

Or are these words are used only before comparatives?

"A bit" and "a little" are synonymous. In contexts like your example, you can use them interchangeably as they are not on a scale. However, "a little" could sound gentler in certain contexts.
Your other examples are wrong. You cannot say "a lot expensive". The general rule is that to modify an adjective like "expensive", you need a word that directly indicates degree or intensity, such as "very", "so", or "quite". We would say "too expensive" or "very expensive". "A bit" is an exception to this as it can act as a soft degree modifier.
You cannot say "much expensive" either, although you can say "much too expensive". "Much" functions as an intensifier when it is an adverb, but on its own, it functions as a quantifier, and you cannot quantify "expensive".

You also can't say "very expensive for me". I'm not sure if there's a good reason why this intensifier doesn't work, while the others are OK. It's just not idiomatic.

Thanks for replying. Aren't a bit and a little quantifiers like much / a lot ? Why can we use them directly in front of adjectives?

@barmar you're right in only one context - when "very expensive" is absolute it doesn't sound quite right if you qualify it by adding "for me" because that implies that it isn't expensive for other people and the statement is no longer absolute. However, something being "very expensive" doesn't mean it is impossible for you to pay for it in the way that "too expensive" does. For example, you could say "childcare is very expensive for me because I have two children".

Right. Context matters. Conversely, "childcare is a bit expensive for me because I have two children" sounds a little weird.

@OA As I said in my answer, "a bit" is the exception, not the other way around. It's used as a softener. "A lot" doesn't work that way. As quantifiers, they are antonyms - you can have "a bit of water" or "a lot of water". I suppose that, over time, we've taken "a bit" and used it for another purpose.

@Barmar That sounds perfectly fine to me. "A bit expensive for me" means it's only just a bit more than you can afford or would like to pay. And it's comparative - you're saying it would be more affordable if you just had one child. "Affordable" doesn't mean what you might expect. When we say "we cannot afford it" in a financial context it can mean we do not have the money. It can also mean we cannot justify the money (because the money needs to be spent on something else). One dictionary definition of "affordable" is "reasonably priced". We all pay over the odds for things sometimes.
